# Did the 1990 Manjil-Rudbar earthquake postpone a massive earthquake in Tehran?

Tags: geology, geophysics, earthquakes, seismology

In [this](https://reliefweb.int/report/iran-islamic-republic/iran-national-disaster-meeting-be-held-tehran) site (published on 6 November 2001) I found the following information:

> Historical data suggest there is a major earthquake in Tehran every 158 years and the last one there was in 1830.

The [1990 Manjil-Rudbar earthquake](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1990_Manjil%E2%80%93Rudbar_earthquake) occured 160 years after the last major earthquake in Tehran, just 2 years after reaching the 158 years interval.

Can we say the 1990 earthquake postponed a major earthquake in Tehran for another century?

It's true that the fault that caused the 1990 earthquake differs from the fault that caused the 1830 one; but the epicenters are close in a geographical sense and the seismic energy of the Earth got evacuated well in the region after the 1990 earthquake.

There was alao a 5.2 magnitude earthquake near Tehran on [2017-12-20](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_earthquakes_in_Iran); but that can't be counted a major earthquake. The 1830 earthquake had a magnitude of 7.1.

P.S. I don't know if evacuated is a good word here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statements such as:

> Historical data suggest there is a major earthquake in Tehran every 158 years

should not be interpreted as a number without variation. It is an average number of years. What the statement doesn't state is the error range for the 158 year time period.

Additionally, such a statement is a very general statement. The statement doesn't state which locations in Iran this applies to, or which fault or faults it applies to. One cannot draw to many conclusions from it.